# Connecting to Twitter Streaming API using perl

Tags: perl, twitter-streaming-api

I am very new to perl, and I would like to read twitter streaming API from perl. I followed [this](http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2014/07/twitter-analytics/) tutorial and got it work and I need something similar in perl. I just need the connecting to Twitter Streaming API and downloading data Any help?

Comment: This may get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448183/twitter-led-timeline/27450473#27450473