# Implementing the Twitter streaming API in Perl, nothing gets printed

Tags: perl, twitter

I am trying to use the Twitter streaming API to demo tweets in the console but nothing is being printed on screen at the moment. I am using the [AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/AnyEvent-Twitter-Stream-0.27/lib/AnyEvent/Twitter/Stream.pm) package to do so, I have taken the OAuth example contained on that page and edited it slightly:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

use AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream;

# to use OAuth authentication
my $listener = AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream->new(
  consumer_key    => "my_consumer_key",
  consumer_secret => "my_consumer_secret",
  token           => "my_token",
  token_secret    => "my_token_secret",
  method          => "sample",
  api_url         => "https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/sample.json",
  track           => "apple",
  on_tweet => sub {
            my $tweet = shift;
            print "$tweet->{user}{screen_name}: $tweet->{text}\n";
        },
);
```

I was expecting this to print to stdout all tweets mentioning "apple", but when I execute this code, the script exits immediately and I am back to the shell. I was kind of expecting this to keep running and keep printing messages to stdout. Have I misunderstood how this works?

Comment: Doesn't use AnyEvent, but definitely did work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448183/twitter-led-timeline/27450473#27450473

Comment: @Sobrique This does work indeed, but it uses the REST API. Looking at the documentation for Net::Twitter, apparently you cannot use the streaming API with it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out the provided example:

http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MIYAGAWA/AnyEvent-Twitter-Stream-0.27/eg/track.pl

It involves creating an `AE::cv` object, and, after setting up the Twitter stream listener, calling `recv` on that object so that it actually loops waiting for data.

Comment: After editing the code to use OAuth, I get tons of these errors when I use that code: `unexpected end of string while parsing JSON string, at character offset 891 (before "(end of string)") at /Library/Perl/5.18/AnyEvent/Twitter/Stream.pm line 126.` usually after displaying one tweet correctly

Comment: Anyway, I guess this answers this specific question :)