# Unexpected end of string error in /Library/Perl/5.18/AnyEvent/Twitter/Stream.pm line 126

Tags: perl, twitter

I am implementing a little demo program in Perl to print some tweet to stdout. This is the code so far (link to the [previous question on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34289970/implementing-the-twitter-streaming-api-in-perl-nothing-gets-printed) for completeness):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream;

if ($ENV{FIREHOSE_SERVER}) {
    $AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream::STREAMING_SERVER = $ENV{FIREHOSE_SERVER};
}

my $done = AE::cv;

binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";

my $streamer = AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream->new(
    consumer_key    => "my_consumer_key",
    consumer_secret => "my_consumer_secret",
    token           => "my_token",
    token_secret    => "my_token_secret",
    method   => "sample",
    use_compression => 1,
    on_tweet => sub {
        my $tweet = shift;
        print "$tweet->{user}{screen_name}: $tweet->{text}\n";
    },
    on_error => sub {
        my $error = shift;
        warn "ERROR: $error";
        $done->send;
    },
    on_eof   => sub {
        $done->send;
    },
);

$done->recv;
```

When I run this, I usually (but not always) get one tweet printed on screen, immediately followed by this error:

```
unexpected end of string while parsing JSON string, at character offset 892 (before "(end of string)") at /Library/Perl/5.18/AnyEvent/Twitter/Stream.pm line 126.
```

Why is this happening? Is it exclusively related to the content of the tweet? If so, is there a way to prevent the script from quitting and to keep monitoring the stream?

Comment: This is a guess, but can you try changing `use_compression` to `0`? There's a bug report on github saying that the option is not working correctly https://github.com/miyagawa/AnyEvent-Twitter-Stream/issues/22

Comment: @AKHolland that was it! Please turn the comment into an answer so I can mark it as accepted ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn off compression, it is bugged in version 0.27 as per [this bug report](https://github.com/miyagawa/AnyEvent-Twitter-Stream/issues/22), and can cause these sorts of issues.

```perl
use_compression => 0
```